# JButton ActionEvent ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton

How I can control the actionListener of two JButtons pressed one after another?

I have got 2 JPanels. In each JPanel I've got a matrix of JButtons named tUsuari and tUsuariCPU

```
 void actionPerformed(ActionEvent){
   /****//
   for (int i=0;i<tUsuari.length;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<tUsuari.length;j++ ){
         if (e.getSource()==tUsuari[i][j]){
            System.out.println("hello");
              for (int r=0;r<tUsuariCPU.length;r++){
                  for (int s=0;s<tUsuariCPU.length;s++ ){
                      if (e.getSource()==tUsuariCPU[r][s]){
                          System.out.println("bye");
                          parent.provaAtac(i,j,r,s);
                      }
                  }
              }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

When I pressed the JButton from the tUsuari it prints "hello", then I pressed a JButton from the other panel ant it doesn't print "bye".

Comment: The event is either going to be "hello" OR "bye" it can't be both at the same time. If you need to modify the state of a button based on a previous buttons action, then you need to maintain some kind of flag to the previous button or maybe us `JToggleButton` instead, and check the state of the toggle buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so many nested loops? Split in 2 parts and fill panels individually... also, what is doing the method: `parent.provaAtac(i,j,r,s);` ?

```
for (int i=0;i<tUsuari.length;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<tUsuari.length;j++ ){
         if (e.getSource()==tUsuari[i][j]){
            System.out.println("hello berlin");
         }
     }
}

for (int r=0;r<tUsuariCPU.length;r++){
     for (int s=0;s<tUsuariCPU.length;s++ ){
         if (e.getSource()==tUsuariCPU[r][s]){
              System.out.println("bye madrid");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. If e.getSource()==tUsuari[i][j], yes, you indeed print out "Hello". But if that condition is true, there's no way that e.getSource()==tUsuariCPU[r][s] can be true, since e.getSource can't be both your tUsari button and your tUsuariCPU button at the same time. Conversely, if you presss the CPU button, you'll fail the first check for it being the tUsuari button, and therefore never get to the check for the CPU button. I suggest creating two different actionListeners, one for each button that does what you want the particular button to do.